# SharePoint Online workflow is subtracting time from all-day date/time fields but not others

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a 2013 List Workflow running in SPO.  I am copying the date/time field from a calendar list and pasting it in another list.  On about half of the operations, it copies the date/time properly.  But if the event is labeled "All Day", the workflow consistently subtracts 5 hours from the time.  So, if the event started at 12:00 AM 11/14/2017, after copy/pasting it shows as 7:00 PM 11/13/2017.  Can anyone tell me why it does this and how to prevent it?  I've double checked that the "Start Date" columns for both lists are identical.

Comment: I deleted the copy-to List, created it again, and used the same Content Type that the Calendar uses to ensure that the Start Time field is identical.  That didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since the workflow consistently subtracts 5 hours from the time, which also changes the date, I simply added an if/then statement that looks at the condition of "All Day Event".  If it is yes, I add 5 hours and 1 minute to the time, which changes the date and time back to the original plus 1 minute.  Not super elegant, but a fast, consistent solution.